# Setting custom toolbarset of FCKeditor in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, fckeditor

I really need Ur help here
I’m using fckEditor 2.6.5 with CI 1.7.2
I used this steps to pluged it into my project : http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/107642/

I want to ask, how to set custom toolbarset in fckeditor???
some of articles said to doing that is by editing fckconfig.js with adding new custom toolbarset over there, than we can call it when we need. it’s about like this :

//fckconfig.js.
//add this sample codes..

```
FCKConfig.ToolbarSets["Custom"] = [
['Bold','Italic','-','OrderedList','UnorderedList','-','Link','Unlink','-']
],['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyFull'] ;
```

then we call in controller

```
$fckeditorConfig = array(
        'instanceName' => 'message',
        'BasePath' => base_url().'system/plugins/fckeditor/',
        'ToolbarSet' => 'Custom', //here we go
        'Width' => '100%',
        'Height' => '400',
        'Value' => ''
        );
        $this->load->library('fckeditor', $fckeditorConfig);
```

but when I load the page, its warned there, that no Custom toolbarset exists.
how to make it???

even, when I tried to only change the option of Default Toolbarset (by removing some options toolbar), not adding custom toolbarset in fckeditor, there is no effect on my page. it still completely show the default toolbar (full toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just cache. FCKEditor is heavy with cache and I've seen the same thing first-hand.

Your code looks correct.